# pyHook event.Time returning irregular Timestamp

Tags: python, unix, logging, time, timestamp

I have been coding a basic keylogger in Python. When checking my log, I observed that the timestamp I am recording using `event.Time` is not a Unix timestamp. What kind of timestamp is it and how can I convert it into a readable format?

```
import pyHook, pythoncom, sys, logging
advancedLog="path\\advanced_log.txt"

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):

    logging.basicConfig(filename=advancedLog, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')

    logging.log(10,chr(event.Ascii))
    logging.log(10,'MessageName: {}'.format(event.MessageName))
    logging.log(10,'Message: {}'.format(event.Message))

    logging.log(10,'Time: {}'.format(event.Time))

    logging.log(10,'Window: {}'.format(event.Window))
    logging.log(10,'WindowName: {}'.format(event.WindowName))
    logging.log(10,'Ascii: {}'.format(event.Ascii))
    logging.log(10,'Key: {}'.format(event.Key))
    logging.log(10,'KeyID: {}'.format(event.KeyID))
    logging.log(10,'--------------')

    return True


hookManager = pyHook.HookManager()
hookManager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hookManager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

The output I am receiving:

```
Time: 561750343
```

Comment: What is ```event```?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python if you don't share your code. It is easier for us to know what format it is in if we know what library you are using, etc.

Comment: Perhaps the system clock is set to 1987?

Comment: @JamieBull no it is not

Comment: Sorry, I was being facetious. The other two comments are the ones that really need answering

Comment: @JamieBull sorry guys. Now I’ve uploaded the code

Comment: @erfanmehraban hope the code helps

Comment: @RushilSrivastava hope the code helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not an actual timestamp. It is the "milliseconds since last boot". If you want to save the current time, you can just use the [time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) library.

> It's not "number of seconds since the epoch".  It comes straight from
>   the "time" member of the Win32 EVENTMSG struct, which is in units of
>   "milliseconds since last boot".

**Source:** [Python.org](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2007-September/006309.html)

Comment: Do you know how can I log the time of the keystroke instead of this?

Comment: @Bogdan please see the updated answer. You can just use the time library to record the current time.